# what part of speech of "proposed" in this sentence "The solution proposed is economically viable" is this?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, whiz-deletion

in this sentence:

> The solution proposed is economically viable

Does it make sense?
If yes, proposed is a adjective, why does it put after solution?

If solution proposed is a subject, what are the rules?

Thanks for helps

Comment: Yes: it makes sense, and yes, "the solution proposed" is a noun phrase functioning as subject. "Proposed" is not an adjective but a past participle verb functioning as predicator of the subordinate clause "proposed", which is modifying the noun "solution". Semantically, it's similar to the relative clause in "The solution which is proposed is economically viable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that sentence is grammatically correct and natural, and yes, "the solution proposed" is the subject.

In that sentence, "proposed" is a *reduced relative clause*. It's reduced by what's called *whiz-deletion*, which means the deletion of a relative pronoun ("that/which/who") plus a "be"-verb ("am/is/are/has been/...").

The deep structure of that sentence looks something like this:

> The solution *which has been* proposed is economically viable.
> or
> The solution *which was* proposed is economically viable.

Because "proposed" is part of a passive structure, it is a *past participle*, not an adjective. The "*which has been/which was*" part can be elided with *whiz-deletion*, leaving only "*proposed*" from the relative clause. The entire relative clause modifies "solution".